# Horizontal list of items: the next to last item is centered, while the last item takes all of the remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a horizontal list of items:

[image: example of a horizontal list of items]

Once scrolled to the end of the list, the second last item needs to be in center, and the last item takes all of the remaining space after it.

[image: example of a horizontal list of items where second last item is centered (green), and the last item takes all of the remaining space]

I've had a success in making the list of items, but not sure what's the best way to implement the desired behaviour of having second last item centered and last item taking remaining space. Here is my current code:

I would appreciate any help or advice for guiding me in the right direction. Thank you!

```css
/* layout */

.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  gap: 21px;
}

.item {
  min-width: 212px;
  height: 254px;
}


/* visuals */

.container {
  padding-left: 11px;
}

.item {
  background: #D9D9D9;
}

.item.green {
  background: #099F9F;
}

.item.red {
  background: #FF6262;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that can be solved using CSS alone - not if you want to specify only a min-width for the items. (With a fixed width, you could use `width: calc(50% - ...)`, with the `...` part being half your item width (plus probably half the gutter width as well.)

Comment: Maybe do a with: calc() on the red item that is like this width: calc(GREEN_BOX_WIDTH - (SLIDER_WIDTH / 2))

Comment: I have updated fiddle. Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/ta4581cv/

Comment: @Ostap Can you please confirm if this fiddle solves your issue so i can post this as answer?

Comment: @Leothelion Thanks for your contibution, I tried it while changing the width of the window, it doesn't seem to show the desired behavior of the green element being centered due to the width of the red element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the width as `calc((100% - item_wdith - 2*gap)/2)`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  width: 220px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 254px;
  background: #D9D9D9;
}

.item.green {
  background: #099F9F;
}

.item.red {
  background: #FF6262;
  width: calc((100% - 220px - 2*20px)/2);
}

/* to illustrate the center */
html {
  background: linear-gradient(red 0 0) 50%/2px 100% no-repeat;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed, and `flex-shrink: 0;` with `width`  makes a better alternative to the `min-width` approach I was using.